# How to set and determine the command-line editing mode of Bash?

Tags: bash, emacs, vi

How to set the `vi` or `emacs` command line editing mode the Bash AND how to determine which mode is currently set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your question is specific about bash:

To set it permanently for every new session:

```
echo 'set -o vi' >> ~/.bashrc
```

or (recommended), add (or change) a line in ./inputrc:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

This will set the editing mode of readline which is used by several other programs beside bash.

It is easy to unset both options:

```
shopt -ou vi emacs
```

To set one, either:

```
set -o vi
```

Or

```
shopt -os vi
```

The same for `emacs`. Setting `vi` unsets `emacs` and viceversa.

To list the state:

```
$ shopt -op emacs
set +o emacs

$ shopt -op vi
set -o vi
```

Or both at once:

```
$ shopt -op emacs vi
set +o emacs
set -o vi
```

To test if `vi` is set:

```
shopt -oq vi      &&   echo vi is set
```

Or (ksh syntax):

```
[[ -o vi ]]        &&   echo vi is set
```

emacs:

```
shopt -oq emacs   &&   echo emacs is set
```

Or:

```
[[ -o emacs ]]    &&   echo emacs is set
```

or, to test that no option is set:

```
! ( shopt -oq emacs || shopt -oq vi ) && echo no option is set
```

Answer (score 20):

To `set`:

```
set -o vi
```

Or:

```
set -o emacs
```

(setting one unsets the other. You can do `set -o vi +o vi` to unset both)

To check:

```
if [[ -o emacs ]]; then
  echo emacs mode
elif [[ -o vi ]]; then
  echo vi mode
else
  echo neither
fi
```

That  syntax comes from `ksh`. The `set -o vi` is POSIX. `set -o emacs` is not (as Richard Stallman objected to the `emacs` mode being specified by POSIX) but very common among shell implementations. Some shells support extra editing modes. `[[ -o option ]]` is not POSIX, but supported by ksh, bash and zsh. `[ -o option ]` is supported by `bash`, `ksh` and `yash` (note that `-o` is also a binary OR operator for `[`).

Comment: It works and it is surprising, that it is that difficult to determine the mode.

Comment: `set -o | egrep -w '^emacs|vi'` will return whether emacs or vi is set.

Answer (score 4):

There is also `bind -V | grep editing-mode`.

`man bash` is huge but well worth reading in depth.